# How to send all images in Another Activity from gridview in Android?

Tags: android

I want to send image through intent from Adapter class to another Activity and slide one by one images on that Activity .I have try but not get the image in other Activity.

Here is Code.

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mThumbIds=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    AQuery aQuery;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public GridViewAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data )
    {
        this.context= context;
        mThumbIds= data;
        aQuery=new AQuery(context);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mThumbIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  mThumbIds;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_gallery_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        aQuery.id(holder.imageView).image(mThumbIds.get(position).get("flag"),true,true);


        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Display.class);
                i.putExtra("pics",mThumbIds.get(position));
                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        return convertView;

    }

    class ViewHolder 
    {

        ImageView imageView;
    }
  }
```

Another Activity

```
public class Display extends Activity
{
    ImageView imgview;

    public void onCreat(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.picture_display);
        imgview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_Grid);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int[] xyz = i.getIntArrayExtra("pic");
        System.out.println("int[] xyz = " + xyz);

    }

}
```

JSON Parsing code

```
public class Photo_Gallery extends Activity
{
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    GridView gridview;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String URL_PHOTO_GALLERY = "http://180.149.241.26:8181/timesofindia/photo_gallery.php";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo_gallery);
        new DownloadJSON().execute();

        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.photoGallery);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Display.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

     private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Photo_Gallery.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Wait");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {

            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL_PHOTO_GALLERY);
            System.out.println("Json String = " + jsonobject.toString());


            try
            {
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("photo_gallary");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++)
                {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    arraylist.add(map);
                    Log.e("arraylist","=" + arraylist.add(map) );
                }
            } 
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args)
        {
            adapter = new GridViewAdapter(Photo_Gallery.this,arraylist);
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If all images are displaying from server then only pass url of that particular image using its position and load in another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `onItemClickListener` from your gridview, just move that code into your Adapter class, like this:

```
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Display.class);

            i.putStringArrayListExtra("pics", mThumbIds);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            context.startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Then in your `Display` acitivty `onCreate()` method get that extras and display the image using AQuery:

```
ImageView imgview;
AQuery aQuery;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_display);
    aQuery = new AQuery(this);
    imgview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_Grid);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> mThumbIds = i.getStringArrayListExtra("pics");
    int id = i.getIntExtra("id", -1);

    aQuery.id(imgview).image(mThumbIds.get(id), true, true);
}
```

Comment: Post your xml of the `Display` activity, and also check id and mThumbIds in that activity. Does mThumbIds have items and id should not be equals -1.

Comment: And make sure that you delete `gridview.setOnItemClickListener(...);` from `Photo_Gallery` activity onCreate()

Comment: :- Why not show image in image view i tried lots of time

Answer (score 0):

you have to make static this variable replace this :

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mThumbIds=newArrayList<HashMap<String, String();
```

to

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mThumbIds=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

and pass this variable through intent like :

```
i.putStringArrayListExtra(key,mThumbIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think there is any need of ArrayList of HashMap(Since you only having an ImageView in your adapter class and no other data is required).

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mThumbIds=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

you can simply have an ArrayList of String URLs. Something Like this.

```
public ArrayList<String> mThumbIds=new ArrayList<String>();
```

and change the code in try block of doInBackground of your AsyncTask to this

```
try
        {
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("photo_gallary");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++)
            {

                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                arraylist.add(jsonobject.getString("image"));

            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If you want to send the whole ArrayList of String URLs to another activity, then you can simply use this in your adapter class.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Display.class);
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("yourKey", mThumbIds);
```

and in your receiving Activity, you can retrieve your ArrayList like this

```
ArrayList<String> mThumbIds=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("yourKey");
```

Comment: :- When i change the code line public ArrayList<String> mThumbIds=new ArrayList<String>(); then issues are occur in JSON Parsing of fetching the images from PHP MySql.

Comment: @anjupatel do you want to pass the whole ArrayList or just HashMap in the specified position to another activity?

Comment: @Romadja :- I want to pass image when click on GridView item in Another Activity and i want to slide one by one images which is include in GridView .

Comment: @anjupatel That is what I am saying you should do something like this in your JSON Parsing 
arrayList.add(jsonobject.getString("image"));

Comment: @Mukesh Rana :- when i implement your code line says = The method add(HashMap<String,String>) in the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String)

Comment: @anjupatel change your ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> to ArrayList<String> and see my updated answer

Comment: That is what I am saying from very beginning to change ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> to ArrayList<String>

Comment: @anjupatel where?? I think you haven't initialised your arraylist. Intialise like this ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @Mukesh rana :-  I initialise like this ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @Mukesh Rana:- Does not show the images in Image View In next Activity.

Comment: You are getting the ArrayList of String urls there?? @anjupatel

Comment: @Mukesh Rana:- It Says - The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>) at the code line imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds);

Comment: @Mukesh Rana:- yah I'm getting the ArrayList of String urls.

Comment: okay okay since you have an arraylist of String URLs, you can not use setImageResource there. you have to use ImageLoader like volley, Aquery(the one you have used in your getView of adapter) @anjupatel

Comment: @anjupatel you need to make changes in this line `aQuery.id(holder.imageView).image(mThumbIds.get(position).get("flag"),true,true);`. Now it should be `aQuery.id(holder.imageView).image(mThumbIds.get(position),true,true);`

Comment: But why not my selected image show in image view in next Activity ?